# magento 2 file uploader frontend append files

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

From what i know magento 2 already uses file uploader https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/45780717/ , how can i use it to create something like they have on this page under tab "Basic Plus UI": http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/index.html

the reason is simple i have a form where user can add multiple files, i want to give user option to add / remove files before user submits the form.

the only thing i was able to find is :
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-components/ui-secondary-uploader.html

which gives us following:

```
<div class="upload-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'uploader'">
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
</div>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
   ".upload-wrapper": {
       "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
           "components": {
               "uploader": {
                   "component": "Magento_Ui/js/form/element/file-uploader",
                   "template": "ui/form/element/uploader/uploader",
                   "previewTmpl":  "ui/form/element/uploader/preview",
                   "allowedExtensions": "jpg jpeg gif png pdf",
                   "isMultipleFiles": true,
                   "uploaderConfig": {
                        "url": "<?php echo $block->getUrl('controller/fileuploadurl'); ?>"
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
</script>
```

but this script starts upload as soon as we have added files.